# Determining if all members of first list are members of second list

Tags: list, prolog

I am having trouble starting this Prolog program that takes two lists and returns true if all members in the first list are members of the second list, and false otherwise.

Examples:

```
?- members([a, c], [a, b, c, d])
true
?- members([d, a, c, a], [a, b, c, d, e])
true
?- members([b, e], [a, b, c, d])
false
?- members([], [a, b, c, d])
true
```

How do I go about doing this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `maplist` on this kind of problem since it follows a standard recursive list traversal:

```
mem(L, X) :- memberchk(X, L).
subset(S, L) :- maplist(mem(L), S).
```

Results:

```
| ?- subset([a,c], [a,b,c,d]).

yes
| ?- subset([c,a], [a,b,c,d]).

yes
| ?- subset([e], [a,b,c,d]).

no
| ?- subset([], [a,b,c,d]).

yes
| ?- subset(S, [a,b,c,d]), S=[_|_].

S = [a] ? ;

S = [a,a] ? ;

S = [a,a,a] ? ;
...
```

Note that the original problem definition does not rule out the case where the subset can have duplicate elements from the superset. If you want to restrict the subsets to having counts of elements less than or equal to the superset, you can use `select/3`:

```
subset([], _).
subset([X|Xs], L) :-
    select(X, L, L1),
    subset(Xs, L1).
```

Results:

```
| ?- subset([a,c], [a,b,c,d,e]).

true ? ;

no
| ?- subset([a,f], [a,b,c,d,e]).

no
| ?- subset([a,a], [a,b,c,d,e]).

no
| ?- subset(S, [a,b,c]), S=[_|_].

S = [a] ? ;

S = [a,b] ? ;

S = [a,b,c] ? ;

S = [a,c] ? ;

S = [a,c,b] ? ;

S = [b] ? ;

S = [b,a] ? ;
...

S = [c,b] ? ;

S = [c,b,a] ? ;

no
```

You'll note that the list `[c,b,a]` is considered a different list in Prolog versus `[a,b,c]` so it is a separate solution. If you want to make the lists behave truly as sets, then that's a different solution.

Comment: `flip(P,A,B):- call(P,B,A).` would fit nicely there. (Saw it first on RosettaCode's Zebra page.)

Answer (score 0):

"We tried nothing and we're all out of ideas"

I would suggest you find a predicate that does that, then look at its implementation.

```
$ swipl
?- subset([a, c], [a, b, c, d]).
true.

?- subset([d, a, c, a], [a, b, c, d, e]).
true.

?- subset([b, e], [a, b, c, d]).
false.

?- subset([], [a, b, c, d]).
true.
```

It is documented here: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subset/2

You can click on the little yellow circle with the colon and the dash to see how it is implemented: [http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/*SWI*/library/lists.pl?show=src#subset/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#subset/2)

```
713 subset([], _) :- !.
714 subset([E|R], Set) :-
715     memberchk(E, Set),
716     subset(R, Set).
```

This definition is about the same as:

```
maplist([M]>>memberchk(M, Set), Subset)
```

This definition always succeeds or fails only once. This is by design.

It could also have been implemented like this:

```
maplist([M]>>member(M, Set), Subset)
```

And it behaves like the suggestion in the comments:

```
?- maplist([M]>>member(M, [a,b]), Subset).
Subset = [] ;
Subset = [a] ;
Subset = [a, a] ;
Subset = [a, a, a] ;
Subset = [a, a, a, a] .

?- length(Subset, _), maplist([M]>>member(M, [a,b]), Subset).
Subset = [] ;
Subset = [a] ;
Subset = [b] ;
Subset = [a, a] ;
Subset = [a, b] ;
Subset = [b, a] ;
Subset = [b, b] ;
Subset = [a, a, a] ;
Subset = [a, a, b] .
```

Comment: `subset(Sub, [a,b]), Sub = [_|_]` fails but `Sub = [_|_], subset(Sub, [a,b])` succeeds

Comment: In an attempt to remove a choice point, your cut also eliminates the discovery of correct solutions. For example, `subset(S, [a,b])` yields `S = []` then finds no more solutions. However, there should be an infinity of solutions: `S = []`, `S = [a]`, `S = [b]`, S = [a,a]`, etc.

Comment: Yes, I understand why it's there (I think!) which is what I was saying: to remove the choice point and avoid, in the cases of one solution, Prolog prompting for and "going back for more". I was just saying sometimes you want Prolog to "go back for more". :)